# How to output data in python scripts?

Tags: python, xml, json, design-patterns, software-design

I'm developing a CLI tool (with python) running in two different modes, the first mode is the classic one where the output is plain text (human readable), and the second mode (activated via a --gui option) is used by a gui in order to read the output of the command and display / process it later.

I'm looking for a way to read the output in a machine format, i thought of xml or json as output, this solution works but is it ok for a CLI tool to output such format, or there are other ways ?

I also thought of implementing a socket to send the output directly to the gui application .

Any ideas will be helpful :)

For example :

```
ls
```

would output:

```
dir1 file1.txt  file2.txt
```

and

```
ls --gui
```

would output:

```
{
  "directory": {
    "name": "dir1"
  },
  "file": [
    {"name": "file1",
    "ext" : "txt"},
    {"name": "file2",
    "ext" : "txt"}
  ]
}
```

or

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
  <directory>
    <name>dir1</name>
  </directory>
  <file>
    <name>file1</name>
    <ext>txt</ext>
  </file>
  <file>
    <name>file2</name>
    <ext>txt</ext>
  </file>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Outputting a known file format is always okay.

Python has a JSON lib in its stdlib: http://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

As well as several XML libs -- the easiest to use being ElementTree: http://docs.python.org/2/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html

Rather than a generic `--gui` flag, which in itself is ambiguous and meaningless (I'd expect it to *spawn* a GUI to show me the data in graphical format), I'd go for `--format=xml` / `--format=json` flags (or if you find that too verbose, `--xml` or `--json`).

EDIT: As for parsing command-line flags themselves, take a look at the `argparse` module: http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html

Comment: Thanks for you response, I know about argparse and the libraries you mentioned above, but I'm still confused about the way my scripts will communicate with a GUI.

Comment: It depends on how you're writing your GUI. Either the GUI calls your program as a subprocess and parses its output, or (if your GUI is in Python) you write your program as a Python module, have your GUI import and call its functions directly. If you choose the latter option, you no longer have to care about your program's output format.

Comment: I'm going with the first option since there are no straightforward GUI tools on python (like Winforms Designer in Visual Studio).